# Same web app, same hardware/software, but web app is rendering differently

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, web

My web application looks perfect on my phone but the CSS looks a little off on my friends phone. We have the same phone, hardware and software, same settings, etc...

I have a normalize.css file in my project and I have tested it on multiple other devices with the same issue occurring.

Example.) My parents have the same phone and laptop. My web app renders correctly on my moms laptop and my dads phone. However my web app renders incorrectly on my moms phone and my dad laptop.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing the issue?? All help is appreciated greatly :)

Comment: Can you describe what you mean with incorrect? Like, are colors wrong? Are boxes differently sized? Preferably supply screenshots, or better yet upload your site somewhere where I can inspect it further. Also, when you say same hardware, do you mean exactly the same or just similar? Like, do they have different resolutions? Because if your CSS depends on pixel sizes the resolution of the screen makes a difference, like that your moms laptop and your dads phone have the same resolution of 1920x1080 but your moms phone has 1270x800 or some such which makes it different.

Comment: It is the exact same hardware, same resolution size, same number of pixels.

Comment: Some of the fields are pushed up about 1.5 rem

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could upload you site somewhere, like jsfiddle, so I can inspect it myself. Anyhow, if they truly are identical then there's no way in hell they render differently unless there's either a virus manipulating the appearance of all sites visited, the usage of extremely old versions of their respective browsers or if they are using different browsers, or if there's a handling error like scrolling down the page by 1.5 rem. If they are in fact identical there's no way they appear differently.

Comment: If I had to wager a guess it's that your html tag has a different font size on your moms phone than on your dads laptop or vice versa. Rem units are based on the root tag font size, so if you're not excplicitly setting that for the html tag then your moms browser will have one default sizing that's used to calculate rem and then your dads browser has another. Try setting the font size of the html tag to something like 16 px and it might solve your issue. Rem is only supposed to be used for font size, use cm or in or vh/vw to size anything that isn't a font.

Comment: Also note that a mobile browser isn't necessarily gonna render the same as the desktop version of the same browser just because they are named the same. Chrome on your phone can look a little different from Chrome on your desktop. An example of this is using vh and vw to get viewport width and height, on your desktop it's based on the size of the visible area in the window while on your phone it's the full size of the device screen.